# Order the array, after detecting particular types of elements

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Suppose an array of numbers (just numbers, but defined as a string, and it has to stay like this, because other reasons) like:
`{ "1234", "0876", "9876", "45614537", "7553", ......}`

As you can notice, all numbers should have 4 digits, except one that has 8 digits.

I want to identify these special cases of 8 digits, and divide into 2 numbers of 4, and put back in the original array, doing a "shift-right" in the original array.

Here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] numbers = { "01", "03", "09", "12", "1517", "24", "72", "3456", "23", "34", "7656" };

    int nr; // The number in the string
    bool number;

    int[] nr_big;
    bool nr_big_bool;

    string nr_char;
    char[] nr_char_array;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
         number = int.TryParse(numbers[i], out nr);


        // Detect big number (For this problem i need also to check if it is a even number
        if (nr % 2 == 0 && numbers[i].Length > 2)
        {
            // At this point "nr" should be the number that want to divide right?
            nr_char = nr.ToString();
            nr_char_array = nr_char.ToCharArray();

            if (nr_char_array.Length > 2)
                // and now???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what´s your porblem on dping so? What have ypu tried? Show your affords and how they failed your expcatations.

Comment: Ok. We know what you want. Can you share what code you wrote for this and what issue you are facing with that ?

Comment: You code includes 2 and 4 digit numbers but not 8?

Comment: Also define what you mean by *divide into 2 numbers*. Given `"45614537"` does that just become `"4561", "4537"` or did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear exactly what you are trying to do and what exactly you mean by "divide into 2 numbers", but, assuming you mean `"45614537"` becomes `"4561"` and `"4537"`, then you can do this (and if not, then it shouldn't be to hard to adapt to whatever it is you need to do):

```
string[] numbers = { "1234", "0876", "9876", "45614537", "7553" };
var result = numbers.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (p,c) => {
    if (c.Length > 4) {
        p.Add(c.Substring(0,4));  // get the first 4 characters
        p.Add(c.Substring(4));    // get the remaining characters
    }
    else {
        p.Add(c);
    }
    return p;
});
```

This uses the [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) function to map your array into a `List` (which you can convert to an array if you *really* need to with `ToArray`). We start with an empty list and then we loop through your original array. If the length of the string is more than 4 (you can change this condition to whatever makes sense to you), we push two substrings on to our list (this is the dividing part, if you want to change that, this would be the place to do it). If not, we just push the current value on to the list.

This code assumes only 4 and 8 digit entries because that was what you asked about. But again, it should be easy to adapt it to whatever you need.